# SQL Cursor Compare Previous Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I want to use cursor to go through the entire line in the table to find the heaviest weight. This is what I got so far that presents the right answer but how do I make it such that it compares the Current Weight with the Previous Weight, and let the cursor print out the heaviest weight?
Thanks :)

```
DECLARE @weight DECIMAL(8,2),
@name VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE Cursor_Eight CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Name, Weight
    FROM [SalesLT].[Product]
    ORDER BY Weight DESC;

OPEN Cursor_Eight

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Eight INTO @name, @weight
PRINT @name + ' with a weight of ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),@weight) + ' is the heaviest product.';

CLOSE Cursor_Eight 

DEALLOCATE Cursor_Eight
```

Comment: Why use a cursor when you can do the same thing with a single set based operation?

Comment: `SELECT TOP(1) Name, Weight FROM [SalesLT].[Product] ORDER BY Weight DESC;` - no messy cursor and horrible RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing necessary.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @product table (name varchar(1), weight decimal(8,2))
insert into @product values
('A',2.00),
('b',1.00),
('c',9.00),
('d',7.00),
('e',10.00),
('f',2.00)

DECLARE @weight DECIMAL(8,2),
        @maxweight DECIMAL(8,2),
        @maxname VARCHAR(100),
        @name VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE Cursor_Eight CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Name, Weight
    FROM @Product
    --ORDER BY Weight DESC;

OPEN Cursor_Eight

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Eight INTO @maxname, @maxweight
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_eight INTO @name,@weight
       if @weight > @maxweight
        begin 
            set @maxname   = @name;
            set @maxweight = @weight;
        end 
end
CLOSE Cursor_Eight 
PRINT @maxname + ' with a weight of ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8),@maxweight) + ' is the heaviest product.';
DEALLOCATE Cursor_Eight
```

Comment: Why the down score?